# Sometimes powershell fails to Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts

Tags: powershell, import-module

I have a simple PowerShell script that is supposed to be run on the Windows Server 2019 64 bit machine. I use the `Get-LocalGroupMemeber` cmdlet in this script, which is part of the `LocalAccounts` module.

The problem is that my script fails to run because the module couldn't be loaded and the worst part is that the problem appears only a few times out of hundreds. Meaning, if I re-run the script right after its failure it will be finished successfully. Another strange thing is that it's not the only module that fails from time to time, the same happens with the SQLPS module.

I use the following batch file for my script invocation because in reality it is invoked from a 32-bit application, whereas the OS version is 64 bit.

```
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%"=="AMD64" (
    set pwshPass=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
) else (
    set pwshPass=%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
)

%pwshPass% -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\Run.ps1"
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
The 'Get-LocalGroupMember' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts', but the module could not be loaded. 
For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts'. 
---$gt; System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts\1.0.0.0\Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---$gt; System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts\1.0.0.0\Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---$gt; System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

Comment: What is the state of the hard drive on that system?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do about hd state. It's reproducible on different machines and in a cloud...